# почему при реализации интерфейса list классом arraylist я не имею доступ к методам arraylist

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
List<String> people = new ArrayList<>(25);

people.ensureCapacity(25); //ошибка компилятора
```

я не понимаю. Да, изначально это просто list, который не имеет такого метода, но мы же создаем новый объект класса arraylist, в котором есть этот метод, разве это не должно работать?

*пожалуйста поправьте, если где-то ошибся*

Comment: Делайте так: `ArrayList<String> people = new ArrayList<>(25);`. `List` общий для тех, кто реализует этот интерфейс (такие как ArrayList), но у самого `List` не будут методы, что появятся у его потомков

Comment: Потому что родительский класс ничего не знает о наследниках

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном вопросе есть 2 аспекта:

1) На этапе компиляции, где собственно и возникает проблема, компилятор только знает, что переменная `people` имеет тип `List<String>` и пытается найти метод `ensureCapacity()`, которого там естественно нет и выдает ошибку.

2) На этапе выполнения конечно же JVM понимает, что `people` на самом деле является объектом типа `ArrayList<String>` и может вызвать метод `ensureCapacity()`, но такова уж семантика Java, что это запрещено, если только не сделать cast (приведение типа) к `ArrayList<String>` типа:

```
        ((ArrayList)people).ensureCapacity(25);
```

или применить рефлексию (`java.reflection`)